# Hide and Show div on button click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm rebuilding a website from scratch and I wanted to know how could I manage to do this :

[image]

When I click on one of the two buttons there's another view appearing.
How can I achieve this ?

I tried this : http://jsfiddle.net/7bqjm1dy/

```js
$("#b1").click(function() {
    $("#first").slideDown();
    $("#sec").slideUp();
});
$("#b2").click(function() {
    $("#sec").slideDown();
    $("#first").slideUp();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="vertical-align:top; display:inline;">
    <button id="b1">Click 1</button><br />
    <button id="b2" >Click 2</button>
</div>
<div>
    <div id="first" style="display:none; background-color:red; width:100px; height:200px;"></div>
    <div id="sec" style="display:none; background-color:blue; width:100px; height:200px;"></div>
    
</div>
```

But it doesn't work the way I want. I want a slideFromLeft and I want to align button and map.

Comment: Link up the button click to some js and change the css class of the element. Then apply a css animation.

Comment: I will post an answer later. I have school to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Updated your fiddle:

**HTML**

```
<div style="vertical-align:top; display:inline;" class="buttons">
    <button id="b1">Click 1</button><br />
    <button id="b2" >Click 2</button>
</div>
<div class="boxes">
    <div id="first" style="background-color:red; width:100px; height:200px;"></div>
    <div id="sec" style="display: none; background-color:blue; width:0px; height:200px;"></div>    
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#b1").click(function() {
    $("#sec").animate({'width': 0}, 'fast', function(){ 
        $(this).hide(); 
        $("#first").show().animate({'width': '100px'});
    });        
});
$("#b2").click(function() {
    $("#first").animate({'width': 0}, 'fast', function(){ 
        $(this).hide(); 
        $("#sec").show().animate({'width': '100px'});
    });     
});
```

**CSS**

```
.boxes, .buttons{
    float: left;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7bqjm1dy/11/)**

Comment: It works but I don't know why my map appear under the buttons ? I copy/paste your css, and classes .. Is it because the image would be too large ?

Comment: Yes even on the fiddle it does that. Thanks for everything ! Now it's up to me to resize the images :)

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this?

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7bqjm1dy/5/)**

```
$( "#b1" ).click(function() {
    $( "#first" ).animate({
        width: "100px",
    }, 1500 );
    $( "#sec" ).animate({
        width: "0px",
    }, 1500 );
});
```

Comment: But if I want to display the first view on default ?

Comment: @NicolasCharvozKurzawa just set the width of the first one to 100px or whatever in the CSS sheet.

Answer (score 1):

combining Deer-Outdoor.nl's answer with the DOM structure below, i think u now have your answer.

```
<div style="vertical-align:top; display:inline;float:left;">
    <button id="b1">Click 1</button><br />
    <button id="b2" >Click 2</button>
</div>
<div style="float:left">
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="sec"></div>
</div>
```

see that those divs now have float:left style attribute. you can also put some margin on that second div to create a space between them.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7bqjm1dy/10/)